# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow: Add List Item Edit Permissions To an Assigned User

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am currently creating a SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow. I am at the step where I have to give list item edit permission to a user who has been defined on a list column named Assigned To. How can I achieve this in SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows?

FYI, in SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflows, there was an Add List Item Permissions which is not available in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Call rest api to assign permission to user.

```
_api/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid='principalid',roleDefId=roleDef)
```

[demo1](http://www.benprins.net/2017/01/03/sharepoint-2013-workflow-changing-permissions-with-rest-calls/) & [demo2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-new-item-permission-using-sharepoint-workflow-and-rest-api/)